# Cannot iterate list of strings into connect function with socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to determine if a list of webservers are listening on a port with the socket library. However I cannot get the iteration to successfully run through the list:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import socket

    myList = ['www.google.com', 'www.spoon.com']
    scanList = []
    port = 80

    def resolveHost(x):
        try:
            h = socket.gethostbyname(x)
        except:
            pass
        return h

    def scan(host,port):
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect(host,port)
        print s.recv(3)


    for x in myList:
        scanList.append(resolveHost(x))

    print scanList

    for x in scanList:
        scan(x,25)


This is returning:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ['216.58.199.196', '207.32.184.61']
      File "C:/Users/Casey/Desktop/projects/dsid_check.py", line 28, in <module>
        scan(x,25)
      File "C:/Users/Casey/Desktop/projects/dsid_check.py", line 18, in scan
        s.connect(host,port)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
        return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    TypeError: connect() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Where I expect to see is the response from those pages, but I dont.

----------  edited source ------------

So I have modified my source to look as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

myList = ['www.espn.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.spoon.com']

scanList = []
port = 80

def resolveHost(x):
    try:
        h = socket.gethostbyname(x)
        return h
    except:
        print "Could not resolve %s" % x

def scan(host,port):
    hostR = resolveHost(host)
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(3)
    s.connect((hostR,port))
    try:
        print s.recv(1024)
    except:
        print "Connection to %s timed out" % x


for x in myList:
    scanList.append(resolveHost(x))

for x in scanList:
    scan(x,port)
```

With this I am not able to connected to a list of web servers that should be online. Reading Alex's recommended library link now.

Comment: Suppose `socket.gethostbyname` raises an exception which you ignore. How can it return `h` when it hasn't been defined? Let the exception be raised.

Comment: You can also define `scanList` as either `[resolveHost(x) for x in myList]` or `map(resolveHost, myList)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the two arguments as a pair in a single tuple.

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> help(s.connect)

connect(...) method of socket._socketobject instance
    connect(address)

    Connect the socket to a remote address.  For IP sockets, the address
    is a pair (host, port).

>>> s.connect('127.0.0.1', 80)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/alexhall/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: connect() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
>>> s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 80))  # works
```

Comment: So I was assuming that the input expected by .s.connect() needed two inputs. So a tuple is treated as a single input?

Comment: @CaseyMcCarthy it's completely nonsensical design, but that's how the method is, yes.

Comment: @CaseyMcCarthy Incidentally this doesn't seem to work anyway because `s.recv(3)` blocks forever. In HTTP the client is expected to send a proper request, the server doesn't just give out data upon connection. Try the requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: What do you mean by it 'blocks' forever? I am still relatively new to programing.

Answer (score 0):

After working through Alex's recommendations I was able to expand on what I previously wanted to do. Please see this as a full example with those mods to the original source code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket, urllib2

httpList = ['www.espn.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.spoon.com']
smtpList = ['smtp.gmail.com', 'aspmx.l.google.com']
scanHttp = []
scanSmtp = []

def resolveHost(x):
    try:
        h = socket.gethostbyname(x)
        print "Resolved %s to %s" % (x, h)
        return h
    except:
        print "Could not resolve %s" % x

def scan(host,port):
    hostR = socket.gethostbyname(host)#resolveHost(host)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(3)
    s.connect((hostR,port))
    try:
        if (port == 80):
            r = urllib2.urlopen('http://'+str(host)).read()
            if 'DOCTYPE' in r:
                print "%s is up" % host
            elif 'doctype' in r:
                print "%s is up" % host
        elif (port == 25):
            r = s.recv(1024)
            if '220' in r:
                print "%s is up" % host
    except:
        print "Connection to %s timed out" % x


for x in httpList:
    scan(x,80)

for x in smtpList:
    scan(x,25)
```

This produces the expected result of checking is the two lists are reachable over the select ports:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Casey/Desktop/projects/service_check.py
www.espn.com is up
www.google.com is up
www.spoon.com is up
smtp.gmail.com is up
aspmx.l.google.com is up

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Great! Since you set a timeout I assume you understand what I meant by blocking forever. Some small improvements you can make: (1) `resolveHost` is better but there's still no reason to hide the exception. Add `raise` to the end and it will be rethrown as it is so that you can see a handy traceback if something goes wrong. (2) Python doesn't need parens around conditions, you can just write `if port == 80:`. (3) You wrote `'http://'+str(host)` but surely we already know that `host` is a string? If not you have bigger problems and this won't solve them.

Comment: (4) Consider `if 'DOCTYPE' in r or 'doctype' in r: print ...` to reduce duplication, or even better: `if 'DOCTYPE' in r.upper()`. (5) This is actually really important: get in the habit of good, meaningful names. Avoid single letter names especially. What does `hostR` mean? It doesn't really matter what the answer is because you shouldn't have to explain it, it should be obvious. (6) What do you want to do if the port is neither 80 nor 25? Consider printing a message or raising an exception so that it's easier to find the problem if the wrong port is entered.

Comment: (7) Avoid broad exception catching such as a bare `except:` or `except Exception:` if possible. They catch way too many errors that you probably don't want to catch. Right now if that block is reached you don't actually know that the problem is a timeout. Consider something more specific like `except socket.error:`. And again it's useful to reraise the exception to see a traceback so you can see where it timed out. (8) Testing for `doctype` is probably not general enough. Try seeing what happens with `gmail.com`. You probably want to check that the status code is between 200 and 499.

Comment: Finally, don't be discouraged by my comments! You're doing well, I just want to help you improve.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers Alex. I will take those considerations and review my final product with them as they make plenty of sense to me now!